# How can i get the name of day from a date in JSP

Tags: java, jsp

Hi i am trying to get the day name from a date, the date will come from another page in a format `(DD,MM,YYYY)` and then the code will get the name of the day from this date.
I tried:

```
<%@ page import="java.io.*,java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="javax.servlet.*,java.text.*" %>
<%
    this line >> Date date = new Date(request.getParameter("DATE"));
    SimpleDateFormat ft = new SimpleDateFormat ("E");
    out.print( "<h2 align=\"left\">" +ft.format(date) +"</h2>");
%>
```

Answer (score 3):

I would definitely go for [JSTL fmt](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/products/products/jsp/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fmt/tld-summary.html) here :

```
 <%@ taglib prefix="fmt" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/fmt" %>
 .....
 <h2 align="left">
   <fmt:formatDate pattern="E" value="${param.DATE}" />
 </h2>
```

You are using *scriptlets* and also using `out.println()` in your JSP , it is a very bad practice.

Please read [How to avoid Java Code in JSP-Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files?rq=1)

Answer (score 1):

[public Date(String s)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Date.html#Date%28java.lang.String%29) is deprecated.

So you should do it like this:

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy"); // Your Input Date Format
Date date = sdf.parse(request.getParameter("DATE"));

SimpleDateFormat ft =  new SimpleDateFormat ("EEEE");

out.print( "<h2 align=\"left\">" +ft.format(date) +"</h2>");
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  String input_date="01/08/2012"; //replace with your value
  SimpleDateFormat format1=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
  DateFormat dformat=new SimpleDateFormat("EEEE"); 
  String finalDay=dformat.format(format1.parse(input_date));
```